# Converting the response of the Google Admin SDK with curly-brace strings with items into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have data that I'm getting from the [G Suite Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list) that looks like this:

```
[{orgUnitPath=/Test, kind=admin#directory#orgUnit, blockInheritance=false, name=No Public Sharing, description=, etag="string", orgUnitId=id:00000, parentOrgUnitPath=/, parentOrgUnitId=id:111111}, ...]
```

How can I convert this into an array like this:

```
[[[orgunitpath, test],[orgunitid,000000]],[[orgunitpath, test],[orgunitid,000000]],[[orgunitpath, test2],[orgunitid,222222]],[[orgunitpath, test],[orgunitid,222222]]]
```

I'm ultiamtely looking to import this data into a SQL datasource in AppMaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

#### Snippet:

```
var res; //[{orgUnitPath:/Test, orgUnitId:id:00000, parentOrgUnitPath=/, parentOrgUnitId=id:111111}, ...]
var array=res.map(function(obj){
    return [['orgunitpath', obj['orgUnitPath']],['orgunitid',obj['orgUnitId']]]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is enough for me to do the rest! I was looking into array.map before asking this, but I couldn't figure out the syntax.